# Docker-compose: Encountered errors while bringing up the project

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, boot2docker

I have the error message:

```
ERROR: for webapi  No such image: sha256:58e2b174484ca40a99ec559bcf6421811d4532cbe009f89d08d430eae9f27050
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

After run commands in Docker Quickstart Terminal:

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up -d
```

It looks like some problems with my image, but I can't find where I should find it. It's built normal and it's throw exception while running my image.

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
 webapi:
  image: clientpanel
  build:
    context: ./src/WebApi
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  links:
    - mongodb
    - rabbit
  ports:
    - "9183:9183"
 mongodb:
  image: mongo
  ports:
    - "27017:27017"
rabbit:
   container_name: dev_rabbit
   hostname: localhost
   image: rabbitmq:3.6.8-management
   environment:
      CLUSTERED: "true"
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: "guest"
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: "guest"
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST: "/"
   ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
```

And my Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:1.1
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApi.dll"]
```

Comment: check your logs with `docker-compose logs` or inside your container

Comment: I see some exceptions with RabbitMQ `Exception:
|  RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable ---> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.ConnectFailureException: Connection failed ---> System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException: Connection refused 127.0.0.1:5672`. But I don't now why it is blocking because I set ports in docker-compose. Maybe you have some experience with this problem @fernandezcuesta?

Comment: I can suspect that from your app you're attempting to connect to `127.0.0.1:5672` instead of `dev_rabbit:5672`

Comment: You should connect to the host "rabbit", not to "localhost" in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the stopped service containers using ***docker-compose rm*** and then try docker-compose up.
We can see the service containers using ***docker-compose ps***.